# Relation between a Gamma prior and posterior in terms of paramters

Tags: bayesian, order-statistics, bayesian-network

I am doing a maths exercise and I have found out that the prior of my parameter is is a inv.gamma (alpha, beta), the likelihood is an exponential distribution. Finally I have discovered that my poterior is a inv.gamma with paramenters higher than the ones in my prior. I was wardering.. Is there any relationship between the parameters of the inv.gamma prior and posterior?

Answer (score 2):

If the likelihood is exponential with unknown rate $\lambda$, then the gamma distribution provides a [conjugate family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions) for the prior and posterior distribution for $\lambda$ where the shape parameter $\alpha$ increases by the number of observations while the *rate* parameter $\beta$ increases by the sum of the observations

The inverse-gamma distribution then provides a prior and posterior distribution for the unknown mean of the exponential distribution $\mu=\frac1\lambda$, and again the shape parameter $\alpha$ increases by the number of observations while  the *scale* parameter $\beta$ increases by the sum of the observations